# denoising an image of type CV_16S

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, graphics, opencv3.0

I have an array of Mat which contain a lot of noise
I just want to remove the noise in the image but keep the bright object in the image. The image is of type CV_16S and thus is on the scale (-32677, 32676). I tried to do fastNLdenoise but apparently it only works for CV_8UC3 and if I try to convert these images to CV_8UC3, I get a pure white image.

```
    for(long int FrameNumber = startFrame; FrameNumber < endFrame; FrameNumber++){

    fp.seekg( BytesPerFrame*(FrameNumber), std::ios::beg);
    char buffer[BytesPerImage];

    fp.read(buffer, BytesPerImage);
    short image[512*512];

    short min = 20000, max=1000;


    for ( int i = 0; i < BytesPerImage; i=i+2 )
    {
        int a;
        a = floor(i/2)+1;
        //  take first character
        image[a] = (static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(buffer[i+1]))*256+static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(buffer[i])));
        if(image[a] < min){
            min = image[a];
        }
        if(image[a] > max){
            max = image[a];
        }

    }

    // Processing the image
    Mat img(512, 512, CV_16S , image);
    img -= (min);
    img *= (32676/max); // (330000/2500);
    img *= ((max/min)/2) + 2;    // 16;
    imgArr[FrameNumber-startFrame] = img.clone();
}


Mat mean = ((imgArr[0].clone())/numFrames);
namedWindow( "Mean", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );// Create a window for display.
for(int i = 1; i<numFrames; i++){
    mean += (imgArr[i]/numFrames);
    waitKey(50);
}


imshow("Mean", mean);

for(int i = 0; i<numFrames; i++){
    Mat temp = imgArr[i].clone();
    subtract(imgArr[i].clone(), mean, temp);
    GaussianBlur(temp, temp, Size(3,3), 1.5);
    imgArr[i] = temp.clone();
}
```

A sample image produced is shown below: 
http://s11.postimg.org/nnhxr7j1f/Screen_Shot_2015_05_27_at_2_51_27_AM.png

Comment: perhaps showing your code will help you!

Comment: is this color 16-Bit input image you want to denoise? is that small White region you want to retain?

Comment: Yes. That is the object we have to track in the series of images but since the noise is amazingly high, processes like stacking and applying hough transform or opticalFlow tracking or contour mapping fail due to detection of noise along with the required object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my results using simple smoothing using Bilateral Filter. Hope this helps!

---

```
Mat mSource_Bgr,mSource_Gray,mBillateral,mBillateral_Gray;
mSource_Bgr= imread(FileName_S.c_str(),1);

bilateralFilter(mSource_Bgr,mBillateral,25,36,100);

imshow("Billateral Smoothing",mBillateral);
```

[image]

```
Mat mCannyEdge,mThres;
cvtColor(mBillateral,mBillateral_Gray,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

double CannyAccThresh = threshold(mBillateral_Gray,mThres,0,255,CV_THRESH_BINARY|CV_THRESH_OTSU);
double CannyThresh = 0.1 * CannyAccThresh;

Canny(mBillateral_Gray,mCannyEdge,CannyThresh,CannyAccThresh); 

Mat kernal_E,kernal_D;
int erosion_size=1,dilation_size=1;
kernal_E= getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT,Size( 2*erosion_size + 1, 2*erosion_size+1 ),
                                   Point( erosion_size, erosion_size ) );
kernal_D= getStructuringElement( MORPH_RECT,Size( 2*dilation_size + 1, 2*dilation_size+1 ),
                                   Point( dilation_size, dilation_size ) );
dilate(mCannyEdge,mCannyEdge,kernal_D);
erode(mCannyEdge,mCannyEdge,kernal_E);

imshow("Canny Edge",mCannyEdge);
```

[image]

```
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
/// Find contours
findContours( mCannyEdge.clone(), contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
{
    drawContours(mSource_Bgr,contours,i,Scalar(0,255,0),2);
}
imshow("Result",mSource_Bgr);
```

[image]